# Defining a macro for inserting words with special characters

Tags: macros, spacing, xetex

So, I am working on a document that has multiple words with special characters (accents, umlauts, etc). I can easily type those in use the special character commands, but I was hoping to create macros for the common words that will be used a lot because a) not everyone working on the document is proficient with latex, and b) to increase human readability of the base code. As an example, this is one of the macros I am trying to create:

```
\newcommand{\Rhun}{
    \begingroup
        \unskip{Rh\^{u}n}
    \endgroup
    }
```

so that someone can type \Rhun and it will output Rhûn.

The issue that I cannot solve is getting it to work with punctuation. If a comma or period comes after the \Rhun (like \Rhun,) then it properly inserts, but there is a space between the word and the comma. I tried putting another \unskip in there at the end, but while it fixed the comma problem, it broke normal usage (no space between Rhûn and the next word). I also tried just making a separate macro for commas, but it defeats the second reason for doing this since I can't include a comma in the macro (\Rhun, can't be defined, and \RhunComma is not really much better than just doing the special character insert).

Any ideas?

Comment: The space is the one following the closing brace. Add a comment character `%` after it. Why do you use `\begingroup` -- `\endgroup` and then another group `{` -- `}`? Why not define `\newcommand\Rhun{Rh\^{u}n}`? You introduce another space after the first opening brace, before `\begingroup`, and then cancel it by `\unskip`; why?

Comment: Check out the `xspace` package. It defines the command `\xspace`, which will conditionally add a space. After defining `\usepackage{xspace}\newcommand\Rhun{Rh\^{u}n\xspace}` you can type `\Rhun next word` and `\Rhun, next word`, and you will get a space in the first case and none in the second one.

Comment: at one point when I was figuring it out the {--} did not seem to be working but the grouping was. I'm sure I was screwing something up though, so I will try that. Thanks for the idea, I will try.

Comment: Isn't it better to simply type in `Rhûn`?

Comment: That is not a possibility on my keyboard, as far as I know it. If it is, then I've been missing something for more than 20 years, lol.

Comment: I think you can define a `compose` key, or can use dead keys, under any OS to input accented characters. In the first case, you would type compose, ^, u to get û, in the second case just ^ and u (provided ^ is a dead key). I have fully internalized the compose key and type characters like ä, ö, ü all the time without delay.

Comment: Any OS of the last 20 years allows to type in with the keyboard at least the most common accents.

Comment: Apart from the method mentioned by @gernot, in Windows also typing the character code apparently still works according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-d13f58d3-7bcb-44a7-a4d5-972ee12e50e0, i.e., hold `ALT` and type the code (0251 for û) on the keypad on the right of the keyboard.

Comment: If you want to use classic commands rather than keyboard to get Rhûn I think it is far preferable to use `Rh\^un` this is much easier to read as you only need to know the simple accent commands from any tutorial rather than having to know multiple docuemnt-specific commands for each word use. It also avoids all problems with spacing.

Comment: @egreg I don't actually know how to type û on a UK keyboard

Comment: I'm on Linux, and while I appreciate the fact that there are workarounds for the keyboard, this was a latex question, and the whole purpose was to allow friends to collaborate without having to teach them much if anything, as they are already adverse to the latex environment to begin with. gernot not only answered my question but pointed out issues that I did not even know I had with my understanding of latex. This question is answered. Also, thank you David, because I was unaware of that form, and probably would have been a simpler answer, but I do have what I wanted working now. Thanks all!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Get a decent OS

Comment: @egreg keyboard layout not OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take care of spaces that you introduce in your command definition.

```
\newcommand{\Rhun}{ % <<< spurious space
    \begingroup
        \unskip{Rh\^{u}n} % <<< spurious space
    \endgroup
    }
```

If you don't want to rely on utf8 characters, which are now the default in TeX installations and which allow you to type accented characters directly, you can define the command as

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand\Rhun{Rh\^{u}n\xspace}
% or \newcommand\Rhun{Rhûn\xspace}
```

The `\xspace` command will generate a space only if a letter follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand\Rhun{Rh\^{u}n\xspace}
\begin{document}
\Rhun and the word `and' are separated by a space, whereas \Rhun, when
followed by a comma, shows no intervening space.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I always wondered why those % were present in other people's code, but never before had I suffered the consequences. Thank you for your answer.